# (React app) PDF retrieved from server in <object> : visible in Mozilla but not in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, pdf, firefox

I am currently experiencing a PDF visualisation issue with my React App, in production environment.

**Context :**
I have PDF files stored in a VM. On my app, when I click on a button, it asks the server for the corresponding PDF file and retrieves it as a Blob. Then, I display the result like this :

```js
<object style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }} data={base64Src} />
```

The pdf file is correctly displayed as following :

[image]

It works fine in local environment.
The magic happens in production environment :
PDF are correctly retrieved from the server (HTTP 200 OK), but sometimes they are not displayed : only a white rectangle appears. This only happens in Google Chrome, and not all PDF do this ! On Mozilla Firefox however, if I open the exact same file, it is always correctly displayed.

Does any one have some hints about this ?

My file is retrieved like this, res being the response from the server :

```js
  const [base64Src, setBase64Src] = useState<any>(null);
  const displayFile = (res: any) => {
    if (res.data) {
      const file = new Blob([res.data], { type: res.headers["content-type"] });
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onloadend = function () {
        const base64data = reader.result;
        setBase64Src(base64data);
      };
    }
  };
```

Comment: Hello, it seems that you are pointing me in the right with the size : the elements that do not appear are bigger than 1MB. I'll look into this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this helps anyone here is how I managed to display the large PDFs in Google Chrome:

```js
const displayFile = (res: any) => {
    if (res.data) {
      const file = new Blob([res.data], { type: res.headers["content-type"] });
      const fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      setUrl(fileUrl);
    }
  };
        

<object height="100%" width="100%" data={url} />
```

I used URLs instead of file readers

Comment: I was also missing the following in my docker compose :

`- "CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY=object-src 'self' data: blob:; frame-ancestors 'self'; form-action 'self' https://some-url; block-all-mixed-content; base-uri 'self';"`